# How to use FormData in jquery for uploading files?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, form-data

I have html form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="formUpload">
<input type="file" name="file" />
<button type="submit" id="sub">Click</button>
</form>
```

My script:

```
 $(function() {
        $("#sub").on("click",function () {
            var form = $("#formUpload")[0];
            var formData = new FormData(form);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'upload.php',
                data: formData,
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function(data) {
                   $("#res").html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

I try to upload file in upload.php, but all is wrong. 
How can I get $_FILES variable?

Answer (score 0):

Every time you click on *submit* button, your page will get refreshed and you won't see any output from this statement `$("#res").html(data);`. Use [`event.preventDefault()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) method to prevent your form from being submitted in the first place. So your Javascript code should be like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#sub").on("click",function (event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var form = $("#formUpload")[0];
        var formData = new FormData(form);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'upload.php',
            data: formData,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data) {
               $("#res").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And in the backend **upload.php** page, you can access the uploaded file data using `$_FILES`, like this:

```
<?php
    if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])){
        $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
        $size = $_FILES['file']['size'];

        // ...

    }
?>
```